# How to care for your critically injured dragon: Medieval edition | Part 1: staying hydrated

Tags: science-based, medieval, dragons, medical

After the Pucci Gang successfully reset D&D universe #405 into a physics compliant version of itself, things went south rather fast.

For instance, somewhere high up in the mountains a village of Aarakocra (yes, that's apparently also the plural form) made an agreement with a female blue dragon, whose territory they were in. Basically, the dragon patrols the area for them and helps defend the village if necessary, in exchange she gets food, shelter, protection, and medical care when needed...

So, the story starts out with said dragon almost dying and subsequently getting hospitalized, and is in a coma (no brain damage) for the most part. Aarakocra should have some kind of a contingency plan for situations like these to keep the dragon alive while she's recovering.

**The village is at around very late medieval level in technology.** Their current spell repertoire includes several levels of Cure Wounds, but that's only a first aid kit that prevents further blood loss and accelerates tissue regeneration, which is still up to the body to do, but such is physics-compliant magic.

Dragons are hexapodal animals, slightly taller than horses (180 cm at the shoulders) that share anatomical features (extensive pneumatization, airsacs, hollow bones) with birds and azdarchid pterosaurs. Dragons can choose to turn off their body's heat generation (basically become cold-blooded) and use ambient temperature instead.

Dragons are omnivorous and they don't eat stuff like gems and precious metals 'cause that's stupid.

The question is just how could this village keep a comatose dragon alive long enough? What does this entail:

- **Keep the dragon hydrated and somehow get nutrients in her, for a start**

The dragon is a vital asset for the village, they will most likely do everything in their power to keep her alive, but less resource-intensive/risky methods are preferred.

Comment: What do dragons eat in your world. I've known fictional dragons to eat: rocks, anything with flesh like sheep or cows, only female human virgins. Not everyone may be familiar with the specific DnD game that you are referring to (if indeed you are). Can you try and be specific about: the technology available in your world, the anatomy of a dragon's throat, the dietary requirements of a dragon?

Comment: Use *Goodberry*, it's a 1st level spell any decent Ranger/Druid should know which heals and provides nourishment.

Comment: To clarify: is this an actual blue dragon as per the canonical D&D literature, or just a blue-colored dragon within the D&D cosmos?

Comment: @Frostfyre A blue dragon "ported" from the 5e SRD

Comment: From what I've seen of 5e, there's not much to go on here. However, you might find the _Draconomicon_ from 3e useful. (There's also one from 4e, but 3e seems more aligned with 5e.)

Comment: arent D&D dragons 'gargantuan'?

Comment: @bukwyrm They are but I already houseruled them in the description into something more believable.

Comment: just wanted to double check it was both d&d and horse size

Comment: @bukwyrm Young dragons and horses are both in the large size category.

Answer (score 2):

According to what I can find on line, D&D Blue Dragons prefer desert climate, so there may not be a lot of hydration needed.  Just keep the sand pit that she burrows in hot and moist and let osmosis do the rest.  As for nourishment, just prop her head up on a mound of sand at an angle that allows you to pour chicken stock down its throat.

Just as important as water and nutrition, you are going to want to find a way of routing lightning down into the dragon's sand pit, if you ever want her to recharge and return to health.  This could be as simple as a lightning rod and some heavy wire, but the principles behind it are way beyond medieval tech level.  The villagers could probably make all the necessary components but wouldn't have any idea what they were or how they are supposed to function.  So set it up that long ago, the dragon taught them how to create and install the rod and grounding wire on a crest high above her sand pit.  As a blue dragon and thus being electrically affiliated, she would understand the fundamentals of electricity long before humans would discover it.

Comment: Oh.. (note to self NEVER use D&D directly in your question ever again)

Comment: Also, you're mixing blue dragons with Skrills from HTTYD

Comment: @Mephistopheles, I see the resemblance between DnD-Blue Dragons and HTTYD-Skrills, but my reference to them being affiliated with electricity was DnD based.  The Blue Dragons have lightning as a breath weapon so it is reasonable that electricity would play a role in their recuperative process.  As for being desert dwellers, that is DnD as well.  Looks like HTTYD lifted a few dragon species from the good ole Monster Manual.

Comment: Whatever, none of those things are in the SRD (what I used as the base) and no, blue dragons are relegated to coastlines, as per the 4e monster manual. It's not far fetched for one to have a lair in the fantasy equivalent of the Andes.